# How to get the hardware time in milliseconds

Tags: vxworks

I am writing a small utility that will get the hardware and software time and print in a file.
This is to check whether both are in sync. I am searching for a vxworks function that prints the hardware time along with milliseconds.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I looked this one up for you in the [VxWorks 7.0 Manual](http://clockLib%20NAME%20clockLib%20%E2%80%93%20clock%20library%20(POSIX)%20ROUTINES%20clock_getres(%20)%20%E2%80%93%20get%20the%20clock%20resolution%20(POSIX)%20clock_setres(%20)%20%E2%80%93%20set%20the%20clock%20resolution%20clock_gettime(%20)%20%E2%80%93%20get%20the%20current%20time%20of%20the%20clock%20(POSIX)%20clock_settime(%20)%20%E2%80%93%20set%20the%20clock%20to%20a%20specified%20time%20(POSIX)%20DESCRIPTION%20This%20library%20provides%20a%20clock%20interface,%20as%20defined%20in%20the%20IEEE%20standard,%20POSIX%201003.1b.%20A%20clock%20is%20a%20software%20construct%20that%20keeps%20time%20in%20seconds%20and%20nanoseconds.%20The%20clock%20has%20a%20simple%20interface%20with%20three%20routines:%20clock_settime(%20),%20clock_gettime(%20),%20and%20clock_getres(%20).%20The%20non-POSIX%20routine%20clock_setres(%20)%20is%20provided%20(temporarily)%20so%20that%20clockLib%20is%20informed%20if%20there%20are%20changes%20in%20the%20system%20clock%20rate%20(e.g.,%20after%20a%20call%20to%20sysClkRateSet(%20)).%20Times%20used%20in%20these%20routines%20are%20stored%20in%20the%20timespec%20structure:%20struct%20timespec%20%7B%20time_t%20tv_sec;%20/*%20seconds%20*/%20long%20tv_nsec;%20/*%20nanoseconds%20(0%20-1,000,000,000)%20*/%20%7D;%20IMPLEMENTATION%20Only%20one%20clock_id%20is%20supported,%20the%20required%20CLOCK_REALTIME.%20Conceivably,%20additional%20%22virtual%22%20clocks%20could%20be%20supported,%20or%20support%20for%20additional%20auxiliary%20clock%20hardware%20(if%20available)%20could%20be%20added.%20INCLUDE%20FILES%20timers.h%20SEE%20ALSO%20IEEE%20VxWorks%20Programmer%E2%80%99s%20Guide:%20Basic%20OS,%20POSIX%201003.1b%20documentation).

try `clock()` - if this doesn't work (not able to test it) search the manual for terms like 'Time' and 'Clock' - yielded good results to me.